# Angular: How to handle two-part directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive

I’m implementing a directive which basically takes a list of footnotes to insert into a body of text, with popover functionality. I have a `text-notes` directive, which is intended to live on a parent element, which loads content and its associated text notes dynamically. The current template starts something like this:

```
<div class="body" data-ng-bind-html="content" data-text-notes></div>
<div id="text-notes"></div>
```

Without the `data-text-notes` attribute, everything renders correctly from the `ng-bind-html`:

```
<div class="body" data-ng-bind-html="content">
  Content with some footnote attached.
  More content, with another footnote.
</div>
```

The desired result with the `data-text-notes` added is something like this:

```
<div class="body" data-ng-bind-html="content" data-text-notes>
  Content with some footnote attached.<a href="#fn1">[fn1]</a>
  More content, with another footnote.<a href="#fn2">[fn2]</a>
</div>
<div id="text-notes">
  <p id="fn1">[fn1] Some footnote text</p>
  <p id="fn2">[fn2] Another bit of footnote text</p>
</div>
```

The content is rendered via the `ng-bind-html`, and behaves exactly as desired. The `text-notes` div is hidden via CSS, and the content of each footnote is to be rendered as a popover (which probably needs to be implemented as part of the directive, or as a related directive).

At present, I have this implemented as follows, but I'm not happy with it. It seems like I ought to be supplying a (pair of) template(s) instead of managing the DOM insertions manually.

```
function TextNotes($timeout) {
    // We use `$timeout` to ensure that the digest cycle has finished and thus
    // that the page is laid out before updating it.
    $timeout(function() {
      var a, insertAtID, insertBefore, targetEl;

      for (var n = 0; n < scope.textNotes.length; n++) {
        // Create a link to the note.
        a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('class', 'text-note');
        a.setAttribute('href', '#' + scope.textNotes[n].id);
        a.setAttribute('data-hg-note-popover');
        a.appendChild(document.createTextNode("†"));

        // Insert the link element after the verse number.
        insertAtID = scope.textNotes[n].ref;
        targetEl = document.getElementById(insertAtID);
        insertBefore = targetEl.firstChild.nextSibling;
        targetEl.insertBefore(a, insertBefore);
      }
    });

    // Separately, and after a delay so that the render above can occur without
    // blocking, insert the notes themselves. Build the string to insert, then
    // insert it separately do avoid updating the DOM a gazillion times via
    // innerHTML changes.
    $timeout(function() {
      var html = '', notesEl, notesId;

      for (var n = 0; n < scope.textNotes.length; n++) {
        // Create the element itself, inserting it at the end of the document.
        notesId = 'text-notes';
        notesEl = document.getElementById(notesId);
        if (notesEl === null) {
          notesEl = document.createElement('div');
          notesEl.setAttribute('id', notesId);
          document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(notesEl);
        }

        html += scope.textNotes[n].content;
      }
      notesEl.innerHTML = html;
    }, 100);
  }

  return {
    link: link,
    restrict: 'A'
  }
}

angular.module('myModule').directive('TextNotes', ['$timeout', TextNotes]);
```

Because the length of the items to insert can be large, I *do* need to render the inserted note content at the bottom of the page separately in some way.

I've read the Angular docs themselves fairly carefully, as well as looked at a few examples, but this is the first *substantive* directive I've implemented, and I don't like this implementation: it *works*, but it doesn't seem quite *right*. Moreover, I'm not sure how well it's going to play with the need to do the popovers.

Comment: I thing you could benefit from using [`ng-repeat`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat) to render the html

Comment: @Cerbrus, that was my thought as well, I'm just still thinking through the best way to do that—and, perhaps unhelpfully, the `<p>` elements in the notes are pre-rendered (though I could change that). `<div id="text-notes"><p ng-repeat="note in a_text_notes_obj_or_list">{{note.content}}</p></div>` or similar…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having something like :

```
<div class="body" data-ng-bind-html="content"></div>
<div id="text-notes">
    <p ng-repeat="note in notes" ng-attr-id="{{note.id}}">[{{note.id}}]{{note.text}}</p>
</div>
```

that way you don't need the directive anymore ... or maybe I misunderstood the example.

**Edit:**

If the added html is a directive that needs to be compiled, you need to do 
something like :

```
$compile(a)(scope); // compile the link before adding it to the dom
// append to dom.
```

Though you might want to run $compile only once after you've added all the links - for performance reasons.

Comment: It's a step in the right direction, and it may well work for the notes themselves. However, I need to insert links into the rendered content in the first body/content div. (I'll update the question to reflect that). That's the part I'm doing dynamically. Rendering the notes content is more straightforward, and I agree that the `ng-repeat` approach should work there.

Comment: Well for that part there's no getting around what you're doing in the directive ... since you have to parse the html and make the replacement ..

Comment: I was hoping that wasn't the case, but it makes sense.

Is there anything necessary to make sure those inserted elements are properly compiled during the `link` phase, so that they can have their own directive attached (for the popover)?

Comment: The edit is super helpful; that's roughly what I was thinking I would need to do, so it's very nice to know I was on the right track. Thanks!